# how to load calender using this json response

Tags: java, json, spring

i am getting one json response like this how to map presentList array to calender

```
{
    "error": false,
    "errorCode": null,
    "message": null,
    "response": {
        "classId": 1,
        "classSubjectMapId": null,
        "studentId": 66,
        "attendance": {
            "presentList": [
                "2017-01-03",
                "2017-01-01"
            ],
            "presentCount": 5,
            "absentList": []
        },
        "totalClassCount": 2
    }
}
```

here i am using Fullcalender api to load full size calender guys help me out this problem.........................

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        header: {
            right: 'prev,next today'
        },

        defaultDate: '2017-01-01',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true,  // allow "more" link when too many events
        height: 572,

        events: 
            [ 
               {
                   start: "2017-01-03",
                   rendering: 'background',
                   color: '#ff0000'
               },  
               {
                   start: "2017-01-01",
                   rendering: 'background',
                   color: '#ff0000'
               } 
            ]     
        });
    }); 
}
```

My controller is this how do i map this help me guys here i am getting present array how do i pass in event.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ShowCalender", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView ShowCalender(HttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("ShowCalender");

        String uri = "http://qnabubackend-env.2fuz4eh5jh.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/attendance/api/student/attendances/v2/1/69"/*+ classId+"/"+ id*/;

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String Attendance = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);

        // build a JSON object

        List<AttendanceCalendarInfo> attendanceCalendarInfoArray = new ArrayList<AttendanceCalendarInfo>();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(Attendance);

        JSONObject objects = obj.getJSONObject("response");

        AttendanceCalendarInfo attendanceCalendarInfo = mapper.readValue(objects.toString(),AttendanceCalendarInfo.class);
        attendanceCalendarInfoArray.add(attendanceCalendarInfo);

        JSONObject obj1 = objects.getJSONObject("attendance");
        System.out.println(obj1);
        //Object presentCount = obj1.get("presentCount");
        //System.out.println("presentCount>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + presentCount);

        JSONArray presentList = obj1.getJSONArray("presentList");

        /* int i;

        for (i = 0; i < presentList.length(); i++) {

            System.out.println(presentList.get(i));
        }
*/              
             System.out.println("presentList>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+presentList);

        model.addObject("theAttendance", attendanceCalendarInfoArray);

        return model;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return exceptionHandler(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The events can also be loaded as a json feed such as given below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        header: {
            right: 'prev,next today'
        },

        defaultDate: '2017-01-01',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true,  // allow "more" link when too many events
        height: 572,

        eventSources: [ 
              {
                url: '/ShowCalender', 
                rendering: 'background',
                color: '#ff0000' 
             }


        });
    }); 
}
```

Have you explored it? link [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/)

Comment: i need to load only attendance": {
            "presentList": [
                "2017-01-03",
                "2017-01-01"
            ],
        },